# How to convert .p12 file to .pem file using Terminal?

Tags: iphone, ios, terminal, pem, pkcs#12

I already have an `development certificate in apple developer portal`. Am developing an iPhone app,i want to integrate Apple Push Notification in this app. I have created a `new App ID` with used the existing certificate and `enabled the Push Notification in this app id`. And i have created a `new Provisioning Profile` used the newly created app id. Before these steps i have created and downloaded the `.cer file from keychain access`. After done these steps i downloaded the newly `created SSL (Apple Push Notification Service SSL certificate) file and installed` in my Mac Keychain Access. Once i installed this file, verified (Green tick mark is there) and `got the .p12 file from this ssl file`.

I followed the apple document `RemoteNotificationsPG.pdf`, in this document they mentioned after saved the .p12 file open the Terminal app and type below commends,

```
openssl pkcs12 -in Certificates.p12 -out Certificates.pem -nodes
```

I have used this in my Terminal app, but the error message is appear that is,

```
Error opening input file Certificates.p12
Certificates.p12: No such file or directory
```

Can you please suggest or guide me where i did wrong or what i missed in these steps? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I stored my Certificates.p12 file in my desktop. Folder path is `Desktop->1/5/2012_Certificate->2/5/12->Certificates.p12`

I have used `'ls' command` in Terminal it is not listing my Certificates.p12 file.

I have typed `cd *path*` this returned `No such file or directory`.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you are invoking the command from the right place, i.e. from the folder that contains Certificates.p12 file? (Try 'ls' in the Terminal before you execute 'openssl ...' - you should get the list of the files contained in current folder).

Comment: Thanks Mr.Manicaesar. I have tried like this Is openssl pkcs12 -in Certificates.p12 -out Certificates.pem -nodes. Response is -bash: Is: command not found. I kept my Certificates.p12 in my desktop folder named as 2/5/12. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: ulu5 already answered the question you asked in comment to my comment ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you in the right directory? Use ls command, does it list Certificates.p12?

EDIT: In the terminal type:

```
ls
```

this will list all the files of the current directory that you are in. If Certificates.p12 is not listed, you are not in the correct directory in the terminal.

To get to the correct directory type:

```
cd *path*
```

where path is the folder containing Certificates.p12. You can drag and drop that folder into the terminal after typing cd. Hit return. Then run the openssl command.

Comment: Thank you for spot response ulu5. Can you please tell me clearly sorry i can't understand directory, is command and list Certificates.p12. Please clarify me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: make sure you type ls and not is.

Comment: Yes ulu5. I have used ls it is listing many file but not showing Certificates.p12. Some files are Desktop, Documents, Downloads, Dropbox, Library, Movies, Music, Picture, Public, Sites, Softwares, AppStoreSubmissionSteps.doc are listing in Terminal but Certificates.p12 not listing what i need to do? Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: read the edit I made. You need to cd into the correct directory. If you can't find it, use the Spotlight tool to search for it.

Comment: Hello ulu5. Thanks. I have opened the Certificates.p12 in finder window and drag the folder in Terminal (/Users/company/Desktop/1:5:2012_Certificate 
-bash: /Users/company/Desktop/1:5:2012_Certificate: No such file or directory) i can't understand what is cd? Where i save the .p12 file in my Mac? If i disturb you please forgive me. Please help me.

Comment: http://ss64.com/bash/ That should help. You need to learn bash commands if you are programming on a mac or any Unix/Linux based machine.

Comment: Thanks.. helpful me this answer i give 10 repution.

Answer (score 6):

Open the terminal and click `ls` to list the items in the current directory,

then if you are not in the folder in which the .p12 is having move to the correct directory by

```
cd directory path
```

for example,

```
cd Downloads
```

Then list the files using and make sure the .p12 file are existing in the directory.

Then convert the .p12 file to .pem file using the following command.

```
openssl pkcs12 -in filename.p12 -out filename.pem -nodes
```

The .pem file which you have created will be saved in the directory which is having the .p12 file.